# Access not closed when added DoCmd.Close line

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have added `DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Import", acSaveNo`

And my access window doesn't close even with this line of code.

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit
Public Function Import()
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim intFile As Integer
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim strHold
strFilePath = "C:\Transfer\FromSynapseTest\TEST.csv"
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("Import", dbOpenForwardOnly)
intFile = FreeFile
Open strFilePath For Output As #intFile
Do Until rst.EOF
   If CDate(rst(3)) >= Date And rst(98) <> 0 Then
       For intCount = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
           strHold = strHold & rst(intCount).Value & "|"
       Next
       If Right(strHold, 1) = "|" Then
           strHold = Left(strHold, Len(strHold) - 1)
       End If
       Print #intFile, strHold
   End If
   rst.MoveNext
   strHold = vbNullString
Loop
Close intFile
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Import", acSaveNo
End Function
```

Since I'm calling the function by macro, I don't think I can do

```
Sub subToCloseForm

    DoCmd.Close

End Sub
```

Also I have tried `DoCmd.Close acQuery, " ", acSaveNo` based on what I read http://www.blueclaw-db.com/docmd_close_example.htm   : If you leave the objecttype and objectname arguments blank (the default constant, acDefault, is assumed for objecttype), Microsoft Access closes the active window

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe It's impossible to quit MS Access?? Any input please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063404/is-there-an-on-close-event-for-ms-access-vba/12063577#12063577

Comment: If all you want to do is close Access, simply use 'Application.Quit'

Comment: What window? Close entire Access? I am not understanding your overall question. Calling DAO recordsets of queries is a background process and needs no call of `DoCmd.Open` or `DoCmd.Close`.

Comment: @Parfait thank you for your comment! I meant the entire Access window!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need code `DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Import", acSaveNo` at all. This command tries to close a query "Import", but you didn't open this query. You opened a recordset, based on this query and you closed the recordset correctly.

If you need to close the form with name "Import", use

```
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Import", acSaveNo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to close Access completely, use:

```
Application.Quit
```

Comment: It's completely closing it without processing the import code. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code `DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Import", acSaveNo` is not necessary as you are opening a recordset, not the query.  rst.close and set rst = nothing is sufficient for memory management.

On a side note, I would recommend including an if statement for stepping through your recordset.  If the recordset is blank, you will receive an error if left unchecked.  Try inserting your for loop inside this if statement:

```
If not rst.eof and not rst.bof then
     'for loop...

end if
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. will try the if statement!